# Unable to connect docker nginx with docker ubuntu

Tags: nginx, docker

I have noticed an issue with docker nginx which is not the case when nginx is running on the host machine (`apt-get install`). Here is how to reproduce my issue:

## solution A: 'nc' on container 1, 'nginx' on container 2, 'curl' on host

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

#### 'nc' on container 1

```
docker run -ti --name agitated_stallman ubuntu:14.04 bash
nc -l 4545
```

#### 'nginx' on container 2

```
LOLPATH=$HOME/testdocker
echo $LOLPATH

mkdir -p $LOLPATH
cd $LOLPATH

subl mple.conf
```

.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;

    location /roz {
        proxy_pass http://neocontainer:4545;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

.

```
docker run --link agitated_stallman:neocontainer -v $LOLPATH/mple.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default -p 12345:80 nginx:1.9
```

#### 'curl' on host

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl http://localhost:12345/roz
```

**ERROR** response from 'nginx':

```
2016/03/04 19:59:18 [error] 8#8: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/roz" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /roz HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:12345"
172.17.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2016:19:59:18 +0000] "GET /roz HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "curl/7.45.0" "-"
```

## solution B: 'nginx' on host, 'nc' on host, 'curl' on host

#### 'nginx' on host

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo subl /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;

    location /roz {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4646;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

.

```
 sudo service nginx restart
```

#### 'nc' on host

```
nc -l 4646
```

#### 'curl' on host

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl http://localhost:80/roz
```

**SUCCESS** response from 'nc':

```
GET /roz HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: run nginx container with `-v $LOLPATH/mple.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

`nginx:1.9` docker image [currently uses](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/e82e776e7507868a887178bc7eaae5c1ed7aa47f/Dockerfile#L8) nginx package from nginx's own repository, not from official debian repository. If you examine [that package](http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/pool/nginx/n/nginx/nginx_1.9.11-1~jessie_amd64.deb), you'll find that `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` does `include` only from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`, and that package ships with pre-included `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # other not important stuff
    # ...
}
```

So your config is not used at all, which explains the `open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/roz" failed` error.

When you install nginx directly on host, you probably use official debian repository, which has different main config file, which in turn does `include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*`, and your config is actually used.